# Attempting to set identical left == right == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding matplotlib error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to make a program that simulates a random walk based on the result of a coin flip and then plot the results on a graph. However, I am constantly getting the error: 'Attempting to set identical left == right == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding', suggesting that the x and y values are the same?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

def Walk(yards):
    
    route_walked = [] 
    
    while yards > 0 and yards < 1000:
    
        route_walked.append(yards) 
          
        flip = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        if flip == 0:
            yards = yards + 200
        elif flip == 1:
            yards = yards - 200

    route_walked.append(yards) 
    
    return(route_walked)

starting_point = Walk(400)
route_walked = []
route_walked.append(starting_point) 

plot_entry = np.ones(len(route_walked))* starting_point
plt.plot(route_walked, marker='o')
plt.plot(plot_entry, 'grey')
plt.xlabel('Steps')
plt.ylabel('Yards')
plt.title('Random Walk')
plt.axis([0, len(route_walked)-1, 0, 1000]);  # Error seems to be referring to this line
```

Full error:

```
<ipython-input-9-2ef9f663f86e>:14: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 0 `results in singular transformations; automatically expanding.`
  plt.axis([0, len(route_walked)-1, 0, 1000]);
```

Thanks

Comment: You've added one point to your walk.  so `len(root_walked)` is 1, and the first two arguments to `plt.axis()` are 0.   Your walk probably needs at least two points before you can plot it.